# Query multiple instance of in same query

Tags: sparql

In this SPARQL query I am getting all wiki items that are instances of `wd:Q11344`. However I need to query from a list of instances of: `wd:634`, `wd:2996394`, etc... How can I query all of them in the same query?

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q11344 .

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
```

I expect to have a list of wiki items that are inside of the list of instances of.

Comment: `SELECT distinct ?item ?itemLabel WHERE { VALUES ?type {wd:634 wd:2996394 wd:Q11344} ?item wdt:P31 ?type .

SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". } } limit 1000000`

Comment: "I expect to have a list of wiki items that are inside of the list of instances of.
" - not sure what you mean, you'll get a "list of tuples" back with the query above

Answer (score 1):

With the keyword VALUES, it's possible to select multiple instance in same query.

```
PREFIX bd: <http://www.bigdata.com/rdf#> 
PREFIX wd: <http://www.wikidata.org/entity/> 
PREFIX wdt: <http://www.wikidata.org/prop/direct/> 
PREFIX wikibase: <http://wikiba.se/ontology#> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?item ?itemLabel 
WHERE 
{
  VALUES ?type {  wd:Q634 wd:Q2996394  }
  ?item wdt:P31 ?type .
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE],en". }
}
LIMIT 10
```

Demo : http://linkedwiki.com/query/Query_multiple_instance_of_in_same_query

Doc: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data